# What is ref in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Going through this [link](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes#naming-processes)

To identify a process,we would be using a Pid. When should a ref be used?

I see this often while message sending/receiving but unable to interpret what role it plays in message interaction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To quote [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id69016)

> A reference is a term which is unique in an Erlang runtime system, created by calling make_ref/0.

This means that this is special data type, it's not an integer, not a list, and not a binary. Especially with `unique` prosperity. It's designed mostly to recognize some places in code.  `make_ref()`, no matter where it is called, will return new value (in boundaries of it's [size](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html) of course).  And just like Fred describes in it's book, it is great for tagging messages, and recognizing if message we receive is in response to one we just send.

Answer (score 4):

In complement to other responses, beware that a ref:

- is not a random value (just start a VM an type make_ref(). several
  times)
- <strike>is unique only in one VM (open a new VM and type make_ref()
  several times, you will get the same result as above) Nevertheless you can create one using a tuple `{node(),make_ref()}`.</strike>

No discrepancy with the documentation, but I made some wrong assumption in the past ... :o). Thanks @Robert for correction!

Comment: A ref is unique over a distributed set of nodes. You should **NEVER** try and interpret the values in a pid/ref/port. They contain their node but how this is represented is **NOT** defined. So refs created on 2 nodes may look the same on each node they are different. You can call `node(Ref)` to get which node it came from, same with a pid to get on which node the process is.

Comment: Refs are not random, and they are created in increasing manner.  So you could compare two, and get which one was created first :)

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: My answer is mostly based on* Learn You Some Erlang, *in particular the [link](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes#naming-processes) provided in the question.*

---

The idea of using references is to *uniquely* identify a given message, so that you can match the messages and their responses - given that the response includes the reference sent in the original message.

We need to identify messages when using named processes that restart because, in this scenario, we can't rely on PIDs, due to concurrency. As is given in the book:

1. `critic ! Message`
2. `critic` receives
3. `critic` replies
4. `critic` dies
5. `whereis` fails
6. `critic` is restarted
7. code crashes

or

1. `critic ! Message`
2. `critic` receives
3. `critic` replies
4. `critic` dies
5. `critic` is restarted
6. `whereis` picks up wrong pid
7. message never matches

There are interleavings where you'll get the wrong PID, or no PID at all, leaving your process unable to receive a response, if it was expecting a response of the form `{Pid, Response}`. This is a consequence of using named processes that restart: you know their PID might change without notice, unlimited times, hence naming them as a convenience to send them messages.

Using a *unique* identifier to tag the message avoids this problem altogether, because you expect the reference to be returned in the response, not a PID.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10029154/2088822) might explain why I use the italics in *unique*. The references are not really unique, but unique enough for practical purposes.

Answer (score 3):

because ref is unique which can identify received message.

for example:

```
A,B two Actors, A want to known B's age

there are 2 solutions:

Method 1:  A send Msg({age}) to B,then B send result Msg({age,10})
but,before A receive this Msg,Actor C send Msg{age,20} to A,
then A got the wrong answer

Method 2: A send Msg({age,Ref}) to B,
no one knowns the Ref except A and B,
then A got the right answer from B.
```