# What does Kernel.make_ref do? What is this Reference type?

Tags: elixir

I ran across the function `Kernel.make_ref/0`, which returns a value of opaque type that looks like this: `#Reference<0.241223140.370933763.163511>`.

What is this, and what is it used for?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337647/what-is-ref-in-erlang/26337986

Comment: I wouldn't have gone so far as to mark this as a duplicate. The question is about Kernel.make_ref, which is elixir-specific, and is also worded better than the flagged question.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I don’t think this is a duplicate, as I’m asking about en Elixir function, and not its analogue in Erlang. If I were asking about a raw erlang call like `:erlang.make_ref`, then it would totally be a duplicate. It’s in `Kernel` however and therefore Elixir-specific.

Comment: There is nothing Elixir-specific, it’s a bare wrapper of [`:erlang.make_ref`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.2/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L700-L702).

Comment: I had to look that up in the source code to figure that out! Based on this post https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ (esp. guideline #3) this shouldn't be closed—someone coming from Elixir isn't going to know it's purely Erlang. This question improves visibility. Marking it as duplicate also assumes `Kernel.make_ref` will never change it's behavior. (Unlikely, yes, but possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are just *almost* unique values that can be compared for equality and pattern matched. So it's kind of `uuid` within Erlang VM. Let's refer to the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/course/advanced#refs):

> References are erlang objects with exactly two properties:
>
> - They can be created by a program (using make_ref/0), and,
> - They can be compared for equality.

Comment: “it's kind of `uuid` within Erlang VM”—that’s wrong. The references are kinda `uuid` within the universe. Their main use-case is to ensure the uniqueness amongst cross-node calls.